# Number of Coin Flips Before Some Sequence Happens?

Tags: probability

The Negative Binomial Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) describes the probability of getting $k$ successes before $r$ failures. For example, on a single 6 sided dice - what is the probability of observing $k$ number of 3's (success) before observing $r$ number of non-3's  (failure) ?

In general, the Negative Binomial Distribution can be written as:

$$P(X = k) = \binom{k + r - 1}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^r$$

**My Question:** I am trying to understand how the formula for the Negative Binomial Distribution was originally derived - how can I come up with this formula myself?

I personally think that the general problem of "$k$ successes before $r$ failures" can technically be modelled using a standard Binomial Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Using this idea of the Binomial Distribution, I think we might be able to find a general pattern, and use this pattern to derive the formula for the Negative Binomial Distribution.

For example, suppose we have a 2 sided coin where the probability of a success is $p_1$ and the probability of a failure is $1-p_1$. For $r$ = 2 failures and $k$ = 3 success. Using the R programming language, I counted every possibility where 2 failures can happen before 3 successes and where 3 successes can happen before 2 failures:

```
library(data.tree)

generate_tree <- function(node, successes = 0, failures = 0) {
    if (successes == 3 || failures == 2) {
        return(node)
    } else {
        for (outcome in c("S", "F")) {
            child <- node$AddChild(name = outcome)
            if (outcome == "S") {
                generate_tree(child, successes + 1, failures)
            } else {
                generate_tree(child, successes, failures + 1)
            }
        }
        return(node)
    }
}

root <- Node$new("Start")

root <- generate_tree(root)

print(root, "level")
plot(root)
```

[image]

Based on the above diagram (assuming I have done this correctly), I can see that there are 4 possible ways that this can happen:

[image]

Now, using the law of total probabilities, I can find the probability that each one of these 4 ways can happen and add them all together:

$$\text{Prob} (3 \text{ Successes before 2 Failures}) = p_1^3 + 3p_1^3(1-p_1)$$
$$\text{Prob} (2 \text{ Failures before 3 Failures}) = 1- \text{Prob} (3 \text{ Successes before 2 Failures}) = 1 - [p_1^3 + 3p_1^3(1-p_1)] $$

**But I am not sure how to continue this problem and derive the formula for the Negative Binomial Distribution based on the Binomial Distribution. Is it possible to take the Binomial Distribution and use mathematical logic to rearrange it and transform it into the Negative Binomial Distribution?**

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

- Note: When $k=1$, the Negative Binomial Distribution becomes the Geometric Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: @user2661923: thank you for your reply! Was the approach I took for this question wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the definition. The formula

$$
P(X=k) = \binom{k+r-1}{k}\cdot p^{k}\cdot \left(1-p\right)^{r}
$$

gives the probability that there are **EXACTLY** $k$ successes before the $r$-th failure. However, your R script gives you the probability that there are **AT LEAST** $k$ successes before the $r$-th failure.

**Deriving the formula**

You stop when you have $r$ failures. Therefore, you have $k+r$ trials and the last trial results in a failure.

- The first $k+r-1$ trials result in $k$ successes. Binomial distribution, the probability is $\binom{k+r-1}{k}\cdot p^{k}\cdot\left(1-p\right)^{r-1}$
- The last trial results in a failure. Probability $\left(1-p\right)$

Therefore, the probability is given by

$$
P(X=k) = \binom{k+r-1}{k}\cdot p^{k}\cdot \left(1-p\right)^{r-1} \times \left(1-p\right)
$$

Comment: @Rehza: thank you so much for your answer! I will correct my R script

Answer (score 1):

Clarification: initial comment transplanted into answer, as a reaction to original poster's followup question.

---

> I am trying to understand how the formula for the Negative Binomial Distribution was originally derived - how can I come up with this formula myself?

The standard approach is to (harmlessly) assume that there will be exactly  $~k+r−1~$  trials, regardless of whether there are  $~k~$  early successes or  $~r~$  early failures.

This strategy :

- guarantees that exactly one of the two events, at least  $~k~$  successes or at least  $~r~$  failures, will occur after exactly  $~r+k−1~$  trials.
- fixes the number of trials to consider, which drastically simplifies the computations.

As to my opinion of your approach:

Here, *wrong* may be an overly harsh description, since it is hard for me to decipher your approach, and since I am generally ignorant of tree structure theory.

From the first part of my answer, you can conclude that the chance of having $~k~$ successes before $~r~$ failures is $$\sum_{i=k}^{k+r-1} \binom{k+r-1}{i} p^i q^{k+r-1-i} ~: ~q = 1-p.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

Notice the similarity between my formula and the one given at the start of the *Cumulative distribution function* section of [the Wikipedia negative binomial distribution  article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  By the way, since my formal knowledge of probability theory is weak, that article seems somewhat confusing to me.

Notice also, that in that article, the convention is followed that when $~0 < a < b ~: ~a,b \in \Bbb{Z},~$ the expression $\displaystyle ~\binom{a}{b}~$ evaluates to $~0.$